# Getting undefined is not a function Error with Every Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, jquery-tokeninput

I AM trying to use different libraries in ASP.Net MVC4 but almost with all I got " undefined is not a function 
" while using jquery functions. what is that and how can I remove it. Every id is correct and everything loaded correctly.

[image]

[image]

and

[image]

why it happen like this and how can i remove it.

Comment: try to use `jQuery` instead of `$` and see

Comment: Have you included jQuery? I guess we could have seen ourselves if you posted the code rather than just a screenshot.

Comment: Check the order of your `<script>`s in the final `<html>` document. `jquery.js` needs to be included before any jQuery plugins. Also check that you aren't including `jquery.js` more than once.

Comment: sorry but Jan Dvorak  it  is also code

Comment: Jonathan Lonowski everything is loading properly :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your link references are pointed to the right place. MVC by default bundles referenced scripts and stylesheets.  See BundleConfig.cs in your App_Start folder.

So if you have this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/tokeninput").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/tokenInput/jquery.tokeninput.js"));
```

then your _Layout.cshtml file should have this in the `head` section to generate the `link` markup:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/js/tokeninput")
```